# Problema esta con el Editor de unity 2022.3 ventana de scene y game (Projecto 2D)

Tags: unity2d

**Problema de unity en la version 2022.3**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen la ventana de hierarchy están todo los objeto como sprites, Tilemap, canvas, y mas, seleccionó un objeto de la hierarchy y no aparece nada en la ventana scene y en la game si, si alguno me podrían ayudar de como lo solucionaron por favor y gracias

**Unity 2022.3**

Removí el paquete 2d y lo volví a instalar para ver si se soluciono el problema pero nada sigue lo mismo si me pueden ayudar por favor y gracias

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!

Comment: Hola marce puente, no me sale ningun texto de error nada y tampoco esta relacionado con el codigo